# Backspace character in .txt files

Tags: python-2.7

I want to write a string with backspace escape characters into a text file, but when I open the .txt it has the  symbol that represent the Backspace. Is there any  way for the backspace character to work in text files? I have tried with \n and it works fine so I don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern text viewers do not interpret the backspace character as removing the previous character, so if you use one of those you won't be able to get it to work.

Comment: Yep, you need an editor that will interpret the \b as it renders the .txt file. Interpreting the \n is mainstream but the backspace not so much. There might be a config setting in NotePad++, that has some color in it.